# No module name 'plotly'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I've installed the packages for plotly by using pip install plotly as well as conda install plotly 
[Command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMF9O.png)

But even after that my jupyter notebook is not reading it and causing error

[No module named plotly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uN65.png)

[No module named plotly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFUCB.png)

Comment: Can you close command prompt and open new one and check if error persists ?

Comment: Did you restart your kernel? Do you have more than one version of python installed?